# How can i plot 3d decision boundry of single-layer perceptron algorithm?

Tags: python, neural-network, data-science, data-mining

I run the algorithm and created the 2D decision boundry but i couldn't find a way to transform it to 3d
Here's the code for 2d decision boundry:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
plt.scatter(X_train[:,0], X_train[:,1],marker='o',c=y_train)

x0_1 = np.amin(X_train[:,0])
x0_2 = np.amax(X_train[:,0])

x1_1 = (-p.weights[0] * x0_1 - p.bias) / p.weights[1]
x1_2 = (-p.weights[0] * x0_2 - p.bias) / p.weights[1]

ax.plot([x0_1, x0_2],[x1_1, x1_2], 'k')

ymin = np.amin(X_train[:,1])
ymax = np.amax(X_train[:,1])
ax.set_ylim([ymin-3,ymax+3])

plt.show()
```

Additional info: i am using a toy classification dataset with 500 iterations

Comment: Is your question how to calculate a 2d surface or how to plot one?

Comment: i managed to calculate and plot 2d decision boundry but i want to do it in 3d, i want to calculate and plot 3d decision boundry of my single-layer perceptron algorithm?

Comment: What you have here is a line, which is a 1D-boundary, albeit in a 2D-space. If I understand you correctly, you want to ask two questions of which the first is how to *calculate*  the 2D-boundary in a 3D-system and the second is about plotting. At the moment, reading the title suggests, that you already have the data and only want to plot, so you might want to change the title

Comment: yes i understood, thanks. Did you know the right answer for this?